# Why request's response initiated from AWS ECS is timing out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have ECS with EC2 instance with load balancer. Internet gateway is working. All this working in public subnet (i know its not right but its not point of my question). All of this is public (security groups, etc...). Incoming requests work fine. When i try to make request from inside from docker container the request is received but i dont get any response. Its like response hanging. I can ping google from EC2, but not from inside the docker container. The docker exposes port 80. I should also mention that i can not directly connect to the EC2 public IP, but it works from load balancer.

For example: I can connect to my app in EC2 from browser but when i try tu call stripe API from inside the app. Stripe registers the change but i dont get response.

I tried to allow everything and everywhere. Edit rules in security groups, ACL, route tables.

**Actual state:**

- Acl is default (allow all)
- network mode awsvpc
- Security groups - allow all
- Public subnet

Comment: If you have anything other than the default rules in your Network ACLs, then please edit your question to include the *exact* details of those ACL rules. Also, please edit your question to include the network mode your ECS tasks are using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using network mode `awsvpc`, the ECS tasks get a separate Elastic Network Interface (ENI) from the EC2 server they are running on. This means the ECS tasks do not share any of the network connectivity of the EC2 instance, and they will need a public IP assigned to their ENI in order for them to make use of the Internet Gateway route in the public subnets they are deployed to.

Unfortunately, ECS tasks running on EC2 do not allow you to assign a public IPv4 address. Your options are:

- Switch your network mode to `host` mode, which will allow your ECS tasks to use the EC2 instance's network connection, which has a public IP address assigned to it and thus can access things outside of the VPC.
- Enable IPv6 dual stack mode on your VPC, add an egress-only internet gateway, at which point your ECS tasks should have a publicly routable IPv6 address and be able to access things outside of the VPC.
- Create a NAT Gateway in a public subnet. Move your ECS cluster into private subnets with a route to that NAT Gateway. Your ECS tasks will then be able to send traffic through the NAT Gateway to access things outside of the VPC.
- Switch to deploying your tasks on Fargate, instead of EC2, which does allow you to assign public IPv4 addresses to ECS tasks.

Comment: I will call out that IPv6 support has some limitations. There is a known working example of the IPv6 dual stack support for Amazon ECS and AWS Fargate here at: https://containersonaws.com/pattern/dual-stack-ipv6-networking-ecs-fargate

You can also try using PrivateLink to provide networking to the tasks: https://containersonaws.com/pattern/ecs-cluster-isolated-vpc-no-nat-gateway